# How to disable expiration password time and lock in Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I set a new password and unblocked all Oracle database users.
Then I used the following rows in SQL developer under System user:

- ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
- ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME UNLIMITED;
- ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME UNLIMITED;
- ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS UNLIMITED;

Everything seemed fine but after a few weeks, I opened the USERS tab in Enterprise Manager and all users had an expired password and were locked out.

The same problem on the following databases: Oracle 11g, 12c, 18c, 19c

It is a database **for testing only**.

Can you advise me how to set it **once and for all**, please?

Please, write me a **step-by-step manual** on how to do it.

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is a really bad idea. You're making it easier for your database to be compromised.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith It is a database **for testing only**.

Comment: Even so, others may stumble by and see this. Someone may have expired/locked those accounts manually - or by some sort of script or software installation.

Comment: As far as I know, when a password is already expired then you can release it only by changing the password. You cannot set `ALTER USER ... PASSWORD NOT EXPIRED`

Comment: Better create some test-users for this. Playing around with the DB internal accounts seems to be a bad idea - even on a Test database.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit

I've changed the password and unlocked all users, and then I set ALTER USER ... PASSWORD NOT EXPIRED.
And after a few weeks, all users had an expired password and were locked again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the profile does *not* change any existing passwords parameters. If a password has an expiry date set, then that will still be in effect until such time as the password is changed.  The profile is *only* consulted at the time that a password is changed.  So here's the sequence you observed:

1. profile had a password lifetime of 'n' days.
2. password for user SCOTT is created or changed; at that time the profile is consulted, and the users 'password expiry date' is set to sysdate + n.
3. you changed the profile to set password unlimited. This does NOT change any existing user attributes. SCOTT still has the password expiry date as set in step 2.
4. Reset SCOTT'S password. At this time the profile is consulted, and it is seen that the password lifetime is set to unlimited, so SCOTT's expiry date is set to null.

Read more [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/exploring-password-lifetime-and-grace-period/).

But I will concur with the others. Even if this is a test system, what you propose (unlocking all accounts) is an astoundingly bad idea.